# Oozie workflow error E0501: Could not perform authorization operation

Tags: hadoop, authorization, workflow, oozie, impersonation

I'm using *oozie 4.3.0* with *hadoop 2.7.3*.

When i want to create and run a workflow, i'm getting the following error:
***Error: E0501 : E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, User: st_jsgane.gane is not allowed to impersonate st_jsgane.gane***

Here is my hadoop's core-site.xml

````
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:19000</value>
  </property>
  
  <!-- OOZIE -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.'st_jsgane.gane'.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.'st_jsgane.gane'.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
</configuration>```


*Thanks in advance for your help.*
````

Comment: Is that really the Linux service account that is running the Oozie server process? with a dot character inside??

Comment: And why would that Linux service account _run_ a job?? It is supposed to impersonate other accounts, not to impersonate itself! Actually I would not be surprised if it was black-listed, just like `yarn` service account

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is not a linux but a windows user. I solve it by creating another user without a dot character.

Comment: But now i'm facing the following issue ***Status HTTP 404 - /oozie/***